# subsquid: extrinsic fee not populated in block.extrinsics

Tags: polkadot, kusama, typescript, subsquid

What config is needed in order to see the fee for each extrinsic?

While following the Transfers example, I try to see the extrinsic.fee

**in processor.ts**

```
export const processor = new SubstrateBatchProcessor()
  .setDataSource({
    archive: lookupArchive(CHAIN_ID, { release: 'ArrowSquid' }),
    chain: {
      url: RPC_ENDPOINT,
      rateLimit: 10
    }
  })
  .includeAllBlocks()
  // .addCall({
  //   name: undefined, // All calls
  // })
  .addEvent({
    name: undefined, // All events
    call: true,
    // stack: true, // causes http 500...?
    extrinsic: true
  })
  .setFields({
    event: {
      phase: true, // Initilization, ApplyExtrinsic, Finalization
      args: true,
    },
    extrinsic: {
      hash: true,
      fee: true,
      success: true,
      error: true,
    },
    call: {
      name: true,
      args: true,
      origin: true, // origin.value.value is the account id of the sender
    },
    block: {
      timestamp: true,
      specVersion: true,
    }
  })
```

**in main.ts**

```js
function getTransferEvents(ctx: ProcessorContext<Store>): TransferEvent[] {
  // Filters and decodes the arriving events
  let blocks: Block[] = []
  let extrinsics: Extrinsic[] = []
  let transfers: TransferEvent[] = []
  for (let block of ctx.blocks) {
    for (let extrinsic of block.extrinsics) {
      if (!extrinsic.call?.origin) continue // no origin, not signed...?
      console.debug(extrinsic)
    }
  }
}
```

The result never has any fee populated:

```json
{
  id: '0000772882-3760a-000003',
  index: 3,
  version: 4,
  signature: {
    address: {
      __kind: 'AccountId',
      value: '0x4ae9eeacbc9d25e40b892b824dd9bb352841374d6f022479a5b507e79eae9e1f'
    },
    signature: {
      __kind: 'Sr25519',
      value: '0x5...'
    },
    signedExtensions: {
      checkEra: [Object],
      checkNonce: 43,
      chargeTransactionPayment: '0'
    }
  },
  tip: 0n,
  success: true,
  hash: '0x629732cd46b7098f18ab3ad9e603a0a6ec6377cf49695feff0b77985c5f23dff'
}
```